# SyncAdapter and Syncing contacts on application server

Tags: android

I was searching for a way to sync contacts to my application server and I stumbled across **SyncAdapter**. I'm new to the concept, so here's my question:-

How does WhatsApp/Facebook/Hike applications create account in Settings>Account section of the android device? Is this related to the SyncAdapter? If yes please provide appropriate explanation or some link to the same as to how should I implement this.

Ultimately, I want to sync my contacts to the application server on user registration, and also update the database whenever user adds/updates the contacts on the device. I'm stuck on this for a long time now so any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an older blog post that demonstrates the account and sync aspects. Even though it is old the content is still relevant to what you need.

http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/

https://github.com/c99koder/AndroidSyncProviderDemo

Answer (score 1):

Get the contact sync project from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r2.1/com/android/exchange/adapter/ContactsSyncAdapter.java?av=f).This code works fine.

If you want more details refer follow the links,

1.http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/
2.http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

If you want to sync periodically, then use background services using Timer.